# С помощью QTextCursor выделить и удалить заданную строку из QTextBrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

Прошу помощи с приведенным в заголовке вопросом.

В `textBrowser` поступают ссылки из процесса опрашивающего сервер `OTRS` на предмет заявок с флагом 'open', если этот флаг меняется на 'close', то строка предназначенная для удаления передается другим сигналом и должна быть удалена из `textBrowser`.

Скитания по интернету и документации не помогли найти ответ.

main.py

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import pygame
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from pyotrs import Client


class Parser(QThread):
    ticket_list_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    new_ticket_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    ticket_list_remove_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    error_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    cycle_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ticket_tuple = []
        self.links_list = []
        self.removed_link = []
        self.ticket_id_list = []
        self.wait_time = None
        self.url = None
        self.log = None
        self.pas = None
        self.sound_file = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.pars()

    def pars(self):
        try:
            response = requests.get(
                f'{self.url}/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/TicketSearch?UserLogin={self.log}&Password={self.pas}',
                )
            response = response.content.decode("utf-8")
            resp_values = eval(response)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'{ex}')
            self.error_signal.emit('Problems connecting to the server')
        print(resp_values)
        client = Client(self.url, self.log, self.pas)
        client.session_create()

        for item in resp_values['TicketID']:
            ticket = client.ticket_get_by_id(int(item))
            self.ticket_id_list.append(item)

            if ticket.field_get("TicketNumber") not in self.ticket_tuple and ticket.field_get("State") == "open":
                self.ticket_tuple.append(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")}')

                if self.cycle_counter > 0:
                    self.new_ticket_signal.emit(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} {ticket.field_get("Title")}')
                    pygame.mixer.init()
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.sound_file)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                link_url = f'{self.url}/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID={item}'
                self.links_list = f'<a href="{link_url}">№ {ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} Title: {ticket.field_get("Title")}</a>'
                print(f'BEFORE REMOVE: {self.links_list}')
                self.ticket_list_signal.emit(self.links_list)

            elif ticket.field_get("TicketNumber") in self.ticket_tuple and ticket.field_get("State") != "open":
                self.ticket_tuple.remove(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")}')
                link_url = f'{self.url}/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID={item}'
                self.removed_link = f'<a href="{link_url}">№ {ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} Title: {ticket.field_get("Title")}</a>'
                print(f'AFTER REMOVE: {self.removed_link}')
                self.ticket_list_remove_signal.emit(self.removed_link)

            else:
                pass
        print(self.ticket_tuple)
        self.cycle_counter = self.cycle_counter + 1

        if self.cycle_counter > 50:
            self.cycle_counter = 1
        print(self.cycle_counter)
        print(f'TIME WAIT: {self.wait_time}')
        QThread.sleep(self.wait_time)


class ConfGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConfGUI, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.sound_file = os.path.join(self.file_path, 'sounds/notice_notice.mp3')
        
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setText(self.sound_file)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_file)

        self.pars_thread = Parser()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.create_session)
        self.ticket_links = self.pars_thread.ticket_list_signal.connect(self.links_add, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.new_ticket = self.pars_thread.new_ticket_signal.connect(self.mb, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.remove_ticket_links = self.pars_thread.ticket_list_remove_signal.connect(self.remove_links, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.error_message = self.pars_thread.error_signal.connect(self.mb, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)

    def get_file(self):
        try:
            self.sound_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберете звук сигнала')
            self.sound_file = self.ui.lineEdit_4.textChanged(self.sound_file)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f'Exception in get folder: {e}', exc_info=True)

    def create_session(self):
        wait_time = int(self.ui.lineEdit_5.text())
        url = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        log = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        pas = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.pars_thread.wait_time = wait_time
        self.pars_thread.url = url
        self.pars_thread.log = log
        self.pars_thread.pas = pas
        self.pars_thread.sound_file = self.sound_file
        self.pars_thread.start()

    def links_add(self, links):
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(links)

    def remove_links(self, removed_links): # этот метод должен удалять строки
        cursor = self.ui.textBrowser.textCursor()
        # cursor.selectedText(removed_links) # TypeError: selectedText(self): too many arguments
        cursor.selection(removed_links) # TypeError: selection(self): too many arguments
        cursor.removeSelectedText()
        cursor.clearSelection()
        self.ui.textBrowser.textCursor(cursor)

    def mb(self, d_msg):
        dlg = QMessageBox(self)
        dlg.setWindowTitle('Attention!')
        dlg.setText(d_msg)
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
        dlg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        dlg.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = ConfGUI()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gui.py

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 550)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 550))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 550))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "New ticket finder"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "URL"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "http://127.0.0.1"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "The interval between requests (sec)"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Звук уведомления"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл"))
```

**Редакция 1:**

Довел функция remove_links до такого вида:

```
def remove_links(self, removed_links):
    cursor = self.ui.textBrowser.textCursor()
    self.ui.textBrowser.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveOperation.Start)
    self.ui.textBrowser.find(removed_links, QtGui.QTextDocument.FindFlag.FindWholeWords)
    cursor.select(QTextCursor.SelectionType.LineUnderCursor)
    cursor.removeSelectedText()
    self.ui.textBrowser.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

Теперь она удаляет последнюю строку списка, но не ищет точного совпадения с переданной ей в переменной.

Скрин интерфейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123420/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо за подсказку. Перевел с плюсов на питон (с помощью онлайн сервиса), но так и не могу разобраться. Напиши пожалуйста для подробнее как мне это сделать...

Comment: find находит и выделяет нужный текст, потом вы выделяете строку где этот текст находится, потом вы удаляете эту строку. Если нужный текст в последней строке, то всё логично.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin добавил скрин. Искомый объект может быть не только в последней строке, потому что тикеты закрываются не по порядку. Вот и получается, что надо найти только переданную строку и удалить именно ее.

Comment: Ок, конечно это можно делать и в QTextBrowser (если removed_links это список, то надо искать строки и удалять их в цикле) но если не предлагается, какое либо ручное редактирование, а просто список строк, то я рекомендую вам использовать QListWidget - будет проще и логичнее.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin что то с QListWidget только больше вопросов возникло, даже не могу понять как гиперссылку вывести в виджет....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241507/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо за советы. Со Qt инструментами разобраться не получилось, буду изучать дальше. Сделал список в который складывал открытые тикеты, удалял из него закрытый, очищал поле и заново выводил открытые. Костыль конечно, но надо было уже сдавать программулину.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример для `QTextEdit`:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton("Clear")
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clear)

    # Удаление последней строки в документе
    def clear(self):
        # Перемещаем курсор в конец документа (он же конец последней строки)
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)

        # Перемещаем курсор в начало строки
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.StartOfLine, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
        
        # Перемещаем курсор в конец строки, но теперь с выделением этой строки
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        
        # Удаляем выделенную строку
        self.textEdit.textCursor().removeSelectedText()

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()

    app.exec()
```